# Physical memory limits inside Windows container with process isolation

Tags: docker, kubernetes, azure-aks, windows-container

It seems to be available under Hyper-V isolation mode.
Is this possible in process isolation mode?

In particular, want to limit under Windows node of Kubernetes.
However, physical memory inside the container seems the amount of all memory capacity is allocated, even if set `resources: limits: memory:`.

Answer (score 0):

For Hyper-V isolation mode the memory limit is 1GB.

For process isolation mode it is unlimited so basically the same memory as the host.

You can find more details documented [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/32724/files#diff-505c72218d90da970c16fdbf0b4f613c).

You can set the limits while using docker-compose, for example:

```
services:
 mssql:
  image: microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express
  mem_limit: 2048m
```

would result with 2GB of available memory.

Please let me know if that helped.